# Error while generating .dll files in Visual Studio 2022. Login authentication using ADSI Api in C++

Tags: java, c++, active-directory, java-native-interface, visual-studio-2022

I want to make a login authentication to my web application(Java). Username and password are created in windows server 2016 active directory. Using that username and password I have to login to my web app using ADSI(Active Directory Service Interface) API in C++ language to connect to the windows server. To do this I have to create the .dll file from the C++ code in Visual Studio 2022. Here I have to add Activeds.lib, adsiid.lib to make the API work. After generating the .dll file to load this in Java System.load() using JNI Concept.

This is the C++ code I used in Visual Studio 2022...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "com_library_ldap_JNIHelper.h"
#include <Iads.h>
#include <adshlp.h>
#include "activeds.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_library_ldap_JNIHelper_authenticateUser
(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jstring uname, jstring pwd) {

const char* uName = env->GetStringUTFChars(uname, NULL);
std::string username = std::string(uName);

const char* pwd1 = env->GetStringUTFChars(pwd, NULL);
std::string password = std::string(pwd1);

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(uname, uName);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pwd, pwd1);

IADs* pObject;

wchar_t wname[20];
mbstowcs(wname, username.c_str(), username.length());
LPWSTR szUsername = wname;
wchar_t wpwd[20];
mbstowcs(wpwd, password.c_str(), password.length());
LPWSTR szPassword = wpwd;

HRESULT hr;

string uAdmin = "Admin";
string uUser = "User";
string uType;
bool res = false;
if (uAdmin == "Admin") {
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://test.local/CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local",
        szUsername,
        szPassword,
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
        IID_IADs,
        (void**)&pObject);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Use the object.
        res = true;
        // Release the object.
        pObject->Release();
    }
    if (res == true) {
        uType = "Admin";
        //return env->NewStringUTF(uType.c_str());
    }
    else
        uType = "NotFound!!!";
}
else if (uUser == "User") {
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://test.local     /CN=Vimaluser,OU=Users,OU=Vimal,DC=test,DC=local",
        szUsername,
        szPassword,
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
        IID_IADs,
        (void**)&pObject);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Use the object.
        res = true;
        // Release the object.
        pObject->Release();
    }
    if (res == true) {
        uType = "User";
    }
    else {
        uType = "NotFound!!!";
    }
}
return env->NewStringUTF(uType.c_str());
}
```

below is the error I'm getting...

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Adsi-JNI, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Adsi-JNI.cpp
1>   Creating library C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\VS Code\Adsi-JNI\x64\Release\Adsi-JNI.lib and object C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\VS Code\Adsi-JNI\x64\Release\Adsi-JNI.exp
1>Adsi-JNI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ADsOpenObject referenced in function Java_com_library_ldap_JNIHelper_authenticateUser
1>Adsi-JNI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IADs
1>E:\Java Program\Library System\src\main\java\com\library\ldap\lib\ActiveDS.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>E:\Java Program\Library System\src\main\java\com\library\ldap\lib\adsiid.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\VS Code\Adsi-JNI\x64\Release\Adsi-JNI.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Adsi-JNI.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And I wrote a code for server connection, but i don't know whether the code is correct for server connection or not. Please help me to solve this problem and also share what are all the things related to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'*  This sounds like you are trying to link a 32-bit (x86) library into a 64-bit program. Just doesn't work.

Comment: Can anyone please share the Activeds.lib and adsiid.lib 64-bit library download link. It will be really helpful to me to solve this problem.